# Почему не получается удалить сообщение vk python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

У меня есть код, который должен удалять голосовые сообщения. Но почему то всегда can't delete. С чем это может быть связано? Т.к айди сообщения всегда 0, беру conversation message id (П.С. Путь указал верно, если использовать print данного показателя выводится id

```
from random import random
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="ой")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "ой")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat \
            and 'attachments' in event.obj['message'] and \
            event.object['message']['attachments'][0]['type'] == 'audio_message':
        vk.messages.delete(group_id=event.group_id,
                           delete_for_all=1, message_ids=event.obj['message']['conversation_message_id'])
```

Сама ошибка:
[image: ...]

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, у бота нет админки, или тот, кто отправляет гс, сам имеет админку(в обоих случаях сообщения удаляться не будут с ошибкой 924)